# Frame delay for variable frame rate video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm working for a video player using ffmpeg for Android. I'm following Dranger FFMpeg tutorial. I'm able to play fixed frame rate videos finely. But have problems with variable frame rate videos. How can I get the delay between frames for a variable frame rate video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on "delay between frames" (like FPS) for display, you should use [AVFrame](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFrame.html).[pts](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFrame.html#a0452833e3ab6ddd7acbf82817a7818a4).

Comment: Ok. But what is the time_base value I have to use to get PTS in seconds? Is it  time_base value of the stream. I used that. But not getting correct.

Comment: Should be in AVCodecContext.time_base units (AVFrame.pkt_pts will be in AVStream.time_base units).